# Mapping the Solr QueryResponse to json format for Faceting, response and response Header

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, solr

This is what i am typing in the code to get the similar response in my RestResponse file:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.IntervalFacet
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.RangeFacet
    import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument
    
data class RestResponse(val response: QueryResult)
data class QueryResult(val numFound: Long, val start: Long, val docs: List<SolrDocument>)

data class RestResponse2(val response: QueryResult, val facet_field: FacetResult)
data class FacetResult(val facet_queries: MutableMap<String, Int>, val facet_fields: FacetField)
```

Here is the link from where i am picking up the QueryResponse class variables

[QueryResponseDocumentation](https://solr.apache.org/docs/7_0_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html)

Please let me know if anyone knows anything.

Comment: Hello, it is unclear to me what your question is. Is it: A) what params to add to the query in order to obtain the desired result or B) how to parse the result? Does an answer in JAVA help you in either case?

Comment: Hey the question the A) part and yes Java can also satisfy the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The java method should look like this:

```
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;    

public String getInfo() {
        
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();

        query.setQuery("text:enroll*");
        query.setFacet(true);
        query.setFacetPrefix("text", "enroll")
        query.setRows(0);
        query.setParam("wt", "json");

        QueryResponse result = getSOLRresults(query);
}
```